# Data Import Apache Solr to Datastax Solr - DateFormat Transformer DIH

Tags: solr, datastax, dataimporthandler, dih

I am trying to import data from Apache Solr to Datastax Solr using DIH. I am able to fetch the document, but when DIh tries to create the document I get the below error in date fields:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid Date String:'Thu Jun 08 16:23:00 PDT 2017'
at org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.parseMath(DateField.java:182)
at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.types.V1TypeMapper.formatToCassandraType(V1TypeMapper.java:166)
at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.types.V2TypeMapper.formatToCassandraType(V2TypeMapper.java:101)
at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3CassandraRowWriter.write(Cql3CassandraRowWriter.java:170)
at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.update.CassandraDirectUpdateHandler.addDoc(CassandraDirectUpdateHandler.java:161)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:595)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:435)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:94)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:70)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:235)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:504)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:408)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:323)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:231)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:411)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:476)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:457)
```

I am using the DateFormat transformer in my DIH but there seems to be no effect on it. DateFormat transformer transforms the date fiels from Apache Solr to the format specified in 'dateTimeFormat' before creating the document to index in Datastax Solr.

```
<dataConfig>
  <document>
     <entity name="sep_byOrderNumber" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" query="OrderNumber:${dataimporter.request.OrderNumberList}" rows="${dataimporter.request.batchSize}" url="${dataimporter.request.urlSource}" transformer="DateFormatTransformer" loglevel="debug">
      <field column="OrderCreateDate" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" />
     </entity>
  </document>
</dataconfig>
```

Can someone please help identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Change your dateTimeFormat to : `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy`**

```
Letter  Date or Time Component             Presentation Examples
y       Year                               Year         1996; 96
M       Month in year (context sensitive)  Month        July; Jul; 07
d       Day in month                       Number       10
E       Day name in week                   Text         Tuesday; Tue
H       Hour in day (0-23)                 Number       0
m       Minute in hour                     Number       30
s       Second in minute                   Number       55
z       Time zone                          Time zone    Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
```

Source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: thank you, but I am still facing the same error. My modified dih-config.xml is as below:



`<dataConfig> <document>
     <entity name="sep_byOrderNumber" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" query="OrderNumber:${dataimporter.request.OrderNumberList}" rows="${dataimporter.request.batchSize}" url="${dataimporter.request.urlSource}" transformer="DateFormatTransformer" loglevel="debug">
      <field column="OrderCreateDate" dateTimeFormat="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" />
     </entity>
  </document>
</dataconfig>`

Comment: Did you reload the core or restart solr and try to reindex data ?

Comment: I deployed the new dih config, reloaded the core and started the dih import. It fetched the documents but failed to index or process or skip due to above error.